# Only one movie is being added to watchlist

Tags: django, django-models

**iam working on a movie app and wants to add movie to watchlist.**

this is my **Movie** model which is on the app **Movies**

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from Crew.models import *
# from Movies.models import Audience_Review
from Details.models import *
# Create your models here.
# Foreign keys are bookmarked

class Movie(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=100,unique=True,blank=True)
    year=models.CharField(max_length=5,blank=True)
    language=models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    release=models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)

    rating=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    audience_score=models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)

    poster=models.ImageField(upload_to='movies/poster',blank=True)
    cover=models.ImageField(upload_to='movies/cover',null=True,blank=True)

    duration=models.CharField(max_length=50,default=None,blank=True)
    streaming=models.ForeignKey(Streaming,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    ott=models.TextField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)

    starring= models.ForeignKey(Actor,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='actors',blank=True,null=True)
    actors=models.ManyToManyField(Actor,related_name='actor',blank=True)
    Characters=models.ManyToManyField(Character,related_name='character',blank=True)

    director=models.ForeignKey(Director,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    writers=models.ManyToManyField(Writer,related_name='writer',blank=True)
    cinematographer=models.ForeignKey(Cinematographer,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)

    based =models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    genres=models.ManyToManyField(Genre,blank=True)

    certification=models.ForeignKey(Certification,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    synopsis=models.TextField(max_length=1000,blank=True)
    trailer=models.CharField(max_length=500,blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

i want to add movies to watchlist,and this is my **Watchlist** model which is in the app Watchlist

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from Movies.models import Movie

# Create your models here.
class Watchlist(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=User)
    movie = models.OneToOneField(Movie,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug=models.SlugField(unique=True,max_length=50)
    date_added=models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.movie.name
```

iam calling this function from this **address** in the **movie detail page.**

```
{% url 'Watchlist:add_watchlist' mov.id %}
```

this is the **path**

```py
from django.urls import path
from Watchlist import views
app_name='Watchlist'
urlpatterns = [
    # function based path
    path('add_watchlist/<int:p>',views.add_watchlist,name='add_watchlist'),
    path('view_watchlist',views.watchlist,name='view_watchlist'),
    path('delete_watchlist/<int:p>',views.delete_watchlist,name='delete_watchlist'),

]
```

this is the **views.py** of watchlist

```py
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from Movies.models import Movie
from Movies.views import *
from Watchlist.models import Watchlist
from django.contrib import messages
# Create your views here.

def watchlist(request):
    # empty watchlist
    user=request.user
    watchlist=Watchlist.objects.all()
    return render(request,'watchlist.html',{'watch':watchlist})


def add_watchlist(request,p):
    movie=Movie.objects.get(id=p)
    user=request.user
    # raise error if movie already exists in watchlist
    try:
        watchlist=Watchlist.objects.filter(movie=movie)
        if movie == watchlist:
            pass
        else:
            w=Watchlist.objects.create(user=user,movie=movie)
            w.save()
    finally:
        return view_movies(request)
    return render(request,'moviesingle.html')

def delete_watchlist(request,p):
    try:
        m=Watchlist.objects.get(id=p)
        m.delete()
    except:
        pass
    return view_movies(request)
    # return redirect('Movie:watchlist')
```

The problem is i cant add more than one movie it this watchlist, with this code, i dont know why...

Comment: What happens when you add a second movie?  Error?

Comment: Nope only the first movie is seen.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong is using one to one relationship between the `Movie` and the `Watchlist` You can fix this by using a `ForeignKey` like this.

```py
class Watchlist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,max_length=50)
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.movie.name
```

explanation:

when using a one-to-one relationship, each movie can be associated with only one watchlist and each watchlist can be linked to only one movie.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use get or create method

```
watchlist, _ = Watchlist.objects.get_or_create(movie=movie, user=user)
```